# WinJS reading local .json files

Tags: json, winjs

I am trying to load local .json files so that I can use with my javascript. I've tried this solution: [WinJS loading local json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510870/winjs-loading-local-json-file)

I keep getting an error when I insert any variable where parsedObject is. I've tried a lot of diferent solutions, but none seem to work.

Comment: Could you show your code, especially where you try to modify the object

Comment: I haven't written a single line of code for that yet =/ Since the linked codes are not working, I have absolutely not a single idea of what to do. Sorry... The autocomplete shows that you can use the namespace Windows.Data.Json, that's what I am trying to look for now.

Comment: Are the files you're trying to load in you package (in your project) or somwhere else?

Comment: They are inside my project. I have a folder named data with the .json inside.

Comment: The code in the answer you linked to is your best place to start. You don't need to use Windows.Data.Json because JS has the JSON.* API built in (Windows.Data.Json, is for C#, VB, and C++ apps that don't have inherent support.) And to follow Jon, you need to show all the code that you've tried and point out where it doesn't work. That'll help us figure out what's going on. In the meantime, check out the File Access sample as a place to start: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597

Comment: I managed to make it work using WinJS.xhr().

Answer (score 0):

JSON files can be retrieved through XHR by setting response type to "json". This way result will be JSON object. Below is snippet as an example:

```
<script>
        // Set url
        var jsonUrl = 'myJson.json';

        // Call WinJS.xhr to retrieve a json file
        WinJS.xhr({
            url: jsonUrl,
            responseType: "json"
            // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx
            // json: The type of response is String. This is used to represent JSON strings. responseText is also of type String, and responseXML is undefined.
            // Note  As of Windows 10, when responseType is set to json, the responseText is not accessible and the response is a JavaScript object. Behavior on Windows 8.1 and earlier remains as described above.
        }).done(

            // When the result has completed, check the status.
            function completed(result) {
                if (result.status === 200) {

                    // Get the XML document from the results.
                    console.log(result);
                    var jsonFileContent = result.response; // returns an object
                    console.log(jsonFileContent);
                    console.log(jsonFileContent.rabbits[0].name);

                    /* The content of file: myJson.json
                    {
                        "rabbits":[
                            {"name":"Jack", "age":3},
                            {"name":"Mac", "age":4},
                            {"name":"Hanna", "age":2}
                        ]
                    }
                    */
                }
            });
    </script>
```